# Laravel 5.3 - Unique field enforces rule on update

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.3

I'm building a CRM inside Laravel 5.3. I have a `rule` like this in my `ClientRequest` `rules` array

`'company_name' => 'required|unique:clients',`

Which means that the Company Name for the Client you're adding needs to be unique in the database. This works, however when I try to update the already existing client, it throws an error saying that the company name needs to be unique.

I tried doing `'company_name' => 'required|unique:clients,company_name,{$this->client_uid},client_uid',`

As `client_uid` is being sent via my `PATCH` request. I was trying to do it that if the `client_uid` being sent with the form matches the `client_uid` of the record just ignore the error but I can't get that bit to work.

Any ideas?

Andy

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update

Comment: @PradyutManna that doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your single quotes, double quotes. If you're using single quotes it will not recognize the `$this->client_uid` as php.

```
'company_name' => "required|unique:clients,company_name,{$this->client_uid},client_uid"
```

Another optie could be (but I prefer the above):

```
'company_name' => 'required|unique:clients,company_name,'.$this->client_uid.',client_uid'
```

Comment: Always the simplest things it seems. Double quotes worked, thank you